How to give each tab page a different colour?
I have created two tabbed pages. I would like to give each page a slightly different colour but both pages are always the same colour. How to I change my code to give what I am looking for? Using ttk.Style() in the subclassed frames always uses blue rather than a separate color for each page. I want to change the page colour NOT the tab colour.
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()

        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('TFrame', background='red')

        self.labelA = ttk.Label(self, text = "This is on MainFrame")
        self.labelA.grid(column=1, row=2, padx = 30, pady = 30)

        self.buttonA = tk.Button(self, text="R 1")
        self.buttonA.grid(column=1, row=3)
        

class SubFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()

        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('TFrame', background='blue')

        self.labelB = ttk.Label(self, text = "This is on SubFrame")
        self.labelB.grid(column=1, row=2, padx = 30, pady = 30)

        self.buttonB = tk.Button(self, text="R 1")
        self.buttonB.grid(column=1, row=3)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        s = ttk.Style()

        unfocus = "gray"
        focus = "#F2C84B"

        s.theme_create( "custom", parent="alt", settings={
            "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0] } },
            "TNotebook.Tab": {
                "configure": {"padding": [5, 1], "background": unfocus },
                "map":       {"background": [("selected", focus)],
                          "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])] } } } )

        s.theme_use("custom")

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.Frame1 = MainFrame(self.notebook)
        self.Frame2 = SubFrame(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(self.Frame1, text='MainFrame')
        self.notebook.add(self.Frame2, text='SubFrame')

        self.notebook.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

        ##--------------------------------##

        self.geometry('800x500')
        #self.resizable(False, False)
        self.title("TABS")
           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()


Have you tried using a standard tk frame and giving it a background color?

You need use unique style names instead of TFrame.

This question is similar to: Python tkinter: Howto set individual colors for Notebook tabs?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Using unique style names instead of just TFrame removed any colour on both pages.

You need to use unique style names for the two frames instead of same style name 'TFrame'.  One of the way is using the id of the object instance:
class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        style_name = f'{id(self)}.TFrame' # build the style name using object ID
        super().__init__(container, style=style_name) # apply the style

        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure(style_name, background='red') # configure the style
        ...

Same for class SubFrame.
